# getting indices of non-unique items in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Given an integer array `I` with `0 <= I[j] < 1000`, with non-unique integer values `I[j]`, and a 'values' array `V` with `V.shape == (1000, )`, how can I create an array `R` with `R.shape == I.shape` such that `R[j] == V[I[j]]` if `I[j]` is unique in `I`, and `R[j] == np.nan` if the value of `I[j]` occurs more than once in `I`?

**EDIT**
As an example, given `I = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int)`, the result should be `V = array([nan, nan, nan, V[3], nan])`, as `3` is the only unique element of `I`.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int)
v = np.random.rand(1000)

r = np.empty(shape=i.shape, dtype=v.dtype)
r.fill(np.nan)

unique, _ = np.unique(i, return_inverse=True)
counts = np.bincount(_)
r[unique[counts == 1]] = v[unique[counts == 1]]

>>> r
array([       nan,        nan,        nan,  0.5650245,        nan])
```